# How do I find a runtime list of all routes that ActiveAdmin has registered?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, activeadmin

I have an activeadmin controller like

```
ActiveAdmin.register UserThing do

  action_item :moderate, only: [:show, :edit] do
    if resource.can_moderate?
      link_to 'Moderate', moderate_admin_user_thing_path(resource), target: :blank
    end
  end

  member_action :moderate do
    # This will render app/views/admin/user_thing/moderate.html.arb
  end

end
```

The call to `moderate_admin_user_thing_path` fails with `"undefined method"`.

1. the method isn't listed in `methods.select{|e| e.to_s.match(/.*_path/) }`
2. It is not in `(ActionController::Base.helpers.methods - Object.methods).select{|e| e.to_s.match(/.*_path/) }`

How can I find the registered routes, to see why the above route fails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list can be found in

```
ActiveAdmin::Helpers::Routes.methods
```